# Designer, (Manufacturer) display above Product Name on all views

Tags: magento-1.9, design

I'm totally new to Magento. But I need to show the manufacturer name above the Product name on the product list page (grid and list) and on the actual Product page. See pics as referenceenter [image: Manufacturer above product name]

I am using magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 2):

set your manufacturer attribute from admin manage attribute section and edit this attribute if does not include in display product list page to **YES**

and in your custom theme files

```
catalog/product/list/list.phtml
```

find place before price display and echo your attribute like

```
 $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
```

again dont forget to

just config it in attribute edit page

Used in `Product Listing -> Yes`